# How to remap Excel spreadsheets to a common schema

Tags: excel, schema, remap

I am volunteering for a non-profit that receives donor information from several different sources.  This information is stored in Excel spreadsheets and each spreadsheet has its own schema (including different names for the same thing).  Their goal is to consolidate all of this information into their donor management system (DMS).  To do this, they create another spreadsheet with a schema that the DMS understands and manually move the data from each of the source spreadsheets into the DMS spreadsheet.  This is a time consuming process that I'd like to automate.

I am thinking of writing some code to do this, it's not too difficult to do in Python.  But before I run down that path, I was wondering if anyone has any Excel tricks or other (hopefully supported) tools that already solve this problem.

I've tried to do some Googling, but haven't seen anything.  I've found that it's difficult to describe the problem to Google search, however.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make a convert spreadsheet for each of the sources then use functions like find() index() and match(). Or you could set up a new series of input sheets and get them to use the new ones... which you have control of the layout.

Comment: So with the convert spreadsheet, I'd basically trade writing macros for Python.  That might be an advantage because they would have a familiar interface (Excel).  Creating new input sheets means they'd still be manually moving one field to another (I think).  That's the process I'm trying to automate.   I like the idea of using Excel macros if I need to automate, however.  Thanks.